# Application force kill callback when user taps the red (-) button on the app icon

Tags: ios, objective-c

When the user force kills the iOS application I need to reset some data in my app. But according to Apple's documentation post ios SDK 4.0 applicationWillTerminate callback method does not get called and the application is killed without being notified. So I would appreciate if anyone helps me find some solution/ other way to capture the event.

Comment: Do it the other way around. Remove your data on `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

Answer (score 0):

You should persist your state by, in your `appDelegate`, implementing

`- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application`

This will be called when the the app is about to enter background.

Read more in the [Apple documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillResignActive%3a)

**Edit**

You can't know if the app is terminated by the user or the system while running in background. If you need to clean up stuff, do it when the app is launched in:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Comment: I need a callback when app is killed not when it goes into background.

Comment: In that case you should clean up the data when your app is started again.

Comment: I need to clean only if the previous instance of the app is killed not for it to resume from background to foreground or for every launch.

Comment: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is only called when the app is started from scratch. You could set a flag (persist it in userPreferences) in - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application to detect when app enter background and remove flag in applicationDidBecomeActive:. If flag is set and you hit didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, you know the app was terminated while in background